# $x^9 - 2x^7 + 1 > 0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

$x^9 - 2x^7 + 1 > 0$

Solve in real numbers.

How would I do this without a graphing calculator or any graphing application? I only see a $(x-1)$ root and nothing else, can't really factor an eighth degree polynomial ...

Thanks.

Comment: You could study the function $x\mapsto x^9-2x^7+1$ (via its derivative), showing it's increasing then non-increasing then increasing, and use it to get the number of real roots.

Comment: I'm in 10th grade and haven't learned any of those yet. Is there a way to do this question without using grade 10 or grade 11 curriculum techniques?

Comment: There is no nice answer--the function doesn't have easily computable roots.

Comment: It looks nice after division by $x-1$: $x^8 + x^7 - x^6 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 - x^2 - x - 1$. Still, it has an ugly behaviour.

Comment: It's easy to show that another root must occur in the interval $[1, \sqrt 2]$. And that there is another root in $[-\infty, -1]$. It's also not too hard to show that these are the only two other roots using simple inequalities. But actually calculating the roots seems very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You know that:$ x^9-2x^7+1=(x-1)(x^8+x^7-x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2+x-1)$.

Note that the second factor is positive for $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, and is $-1$ for $x=0$ so it has at least two real roots.

You can use the [Sturm theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) to find how many real roots has $x^8+x^7-x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2+x-1$, but it is very laborious, and don't gives the value of the roots.

A numerical calculus show that it has really only two roots $x \sim 1.38$ and $x \sim -1.44$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting it as $$x^7(x^2-2)=x^7(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})>-1$$ we see it holds for $-\sqrt{2}\le x\le0$ and $\require\color \color\red{x\ge \sqrt{2}}$. We can extend the former interval as $\color\red {-\sqrt{2}\le x < 1}$ noting that the LHS is decreasing in $(0,1)$ and it becomes $-1$ when $x=1$. With a similar reasoning, we could extend both our two intervals respectively further to the left and to the right, but as Emilio pointed out, only numerical approximations are effective.